# How can I open Python3.3 IDLE from command line on windows?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

I am trying to do like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2345680/2886003) answer to the "same" question. But doesn't work.

How can I open Python3.3 IDLE from command line on windows?

Comment: There seems to be no reason for this not to be an edit + answer combination to the original question, explaining what's insufficient about the accepted answer. For that reason I'm closing as duplicate.

Comment: @Veedrac I thought that it could be python 3 specific and therefore a maybe a separate question, while writing the question I found the answer, so I posted it. But I will post there an answer.

Comment: Thank you. If you strongly disagree with my verdict, you can always discuss on [Meta].

Answer (score 1):

You need to do as stated in the *main*.py file of the idelib folder (C:\Python33\Lib\idlelib)

> IDLE main entry point
>
> Run IDLE as python -m idlelib

So with `python -m idlelib <script_to_edit>` you will be able to open and edit the script with idle.
I haven't checked with previous versions but it could have the same usage.