# How do I get the right installation of python?

Tags: python, windows, installation, python-idle

I'm having trouble finding the right installation of python, and I am on windows.

When I first installed python (IDLE) by going to https://python.org, and downloading the version, I did not know that there was a version of python in the microsoft store for windows.

For some reason, whenever I needed to run commands in the shell, say, install a python module, I needed to do this: `py -m pip install module`, instead of the traditional: `python -m pip install module`.

I don't know why python was called "py", when I ran: `where python`, it showed a file path that ended with "python.exe", so clearly python is being installed. And of course, IDLE and the python interpreter and all of python always worked...but I never figured out the reason python was called "py".

Now I saw that there was a version of IDLE, but for windows, in the microsoft store. So I went and installed it, but instead of giving me an IDLE app, like I expected, instead it gave me the windows terminal, with only the shell, not where I can write actual files (multiple lines), just a shell, which is useless to me.

Of course, now `python -m pip install module` works, but I think my system is completely messed up. Because when I tried: `python -m pip show keyboard` (keyboard is a module that I already have installed), I got this error warning that the package was not found. But when I tried: `py -m pip show keyboard`, it worked.

My assumption is that I now have *two* versions of python, the regular IDLE one that I installed (that is named py), and the new one that I just installed recently, which is not what was expected. I'll take this moment to note that when I installed the new one, my old one was still installed. Is it possible that the old one interfered with the new one being installed (so that I can write multiple lines and have the usual IDLE format)?

I don't just want a shell, I want the regular IDLE, where I can write multiple lines of code and run it, and I also want to know why python was originally named py at the start?

UPDATE:

Resolved, looks like I can just open IDLE from the terminal, by typing in `idle`, it's that simple. I would have preferred a faster method to open the app, but it's no big issue.

Comment: (1) Regarding `py`: https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher (2) To start `idle` you can either find an exe in the `Scripts` directory of the Python installation or use command line: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345607/starting-python-idle-from-command-line-to-edit-scripts where you can replace `python` by `py`, `pythonw` or `pyw` (the `w` variants detach from console).

Comment: Is it possible to open IDLE directly from windows apps? Or do I have to go to the command line each time?

Comment: If you use vscode, the pip manager extension can install packages using the Python version that is working. Visual Studio has an even better pip manager.

Comment: I don't know how the Microsoft store works and if a shortcut can be created like for regular applications.

Comment: `py` is a separate python launcher app that can run any version of python installed with a python.org installer.  I can run any of 6 python versions with `py -3.8` to `py -3.13`.  Adding `-m idlelib` starts IDLE with that version. One can start IDLE from the start menu.  Each `pythonx.y` entry expands to a list starting with IDLE.  I keep IDLE pinned to my taskbar.  One can also run IDLE from File Explorer by right clicking a `.py` file.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "open IDLE directly from windows apps".  The python statement `import idlelib.idle` works within python.  It blocks further execution until IDLE is closed.

Comment: I mean from windows start, like when I click the windows app button, it shows a list of apps that I can click on. I don't want to have to open the cmd prompt each time.

Comment: Ok.  I explained Start in previous comment.  When the installer asks about installing shortcuts/icons, it means installing them in the Start menu.  That should have been selected by default.  If that did not happen, one can rerun the installer and select 'Repair' or 'Modify' (whichever is offered) and make sure to select the option.